# How to determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{n^2-5n+1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^{n^2}$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n^2-5n+1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^{n^2}$$
Using root test seems not a efficient way since I got stuck without knowing what to do next 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2-5n+1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^{n}$$

Using ratio test is too complicated

$$\left(\frac{(n+1)^2-5(n+1)+1}{(n+1)^2-4(n+1)+2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}=\left(\frac{n^2-3n-3}{n^2-2n-1}\right)^{n^2+2n+1}$$
$$\to\left(\frac{(n+1)^2-5(n+1)+1}{(n+1)^2-4(n+1)+2}*\frac{n^2-4n+2}{n^2-5n+1}\right)^{n^2}*\left(\frac{n^2-3n-3}{n^2-2n-1}\right)^{2n}*\frac{n^2-3n-3}{n^2-2n-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete your root test:

$$=\lim_n\left[\left(1+\frac{-5n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^{\frac{n^2-4n+2}{-5n-1}}\right]^{\frac{n(-5n-1)}{n^2-4n+2}}=e^{\lim_n\frac{n(-5n-1)}{n^2-4n+2}}=e^{-5}<1$$

Answer (score 2):

The general term decays like $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\approx e^{-n}$ hence the series is convergent.