# how does one solve $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{n^{2}-2n+1}{n^{2}-4n+2})^{n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I cant use lhopital's rule here is my attempt:

Limit of $(\frac{n^{2}-2n+1}{n^{2}-4n+2})^{n}$ =$e^{\lim_{n\to \infty} n\times \ln(\frac{1 -2-n +\frac{1}{n^{2}}}{1 -\frac{4}{n} +\frac{2}{n^{2}}})}$
I got stuck here

Comment: The limit on the inside of the log can be handled by dividing the numerator and denominator by the highest power of n in the denominator and taking the limit, or you can use L'Hospitals rule on it now as it is of the form of infinity over infinity

Comment: You don't need to divide the numerator and denominator by $n^2$ inside the logarithm.  Instead, change the $n$ out in front to $1/(1/n)$ and use l'Hopital's rule.  If you are not allowed to use l'Hopital's rule, you must transform it to look like a limit for $e$.

Comment: Rather similar limit was calculated in the solution of this problem: [How to determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{n^2-5n+1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^{n^2}$ converges or diverges](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1263557). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20(%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E%7B2%7D-2n%2B1%7D%7Bn%5E%7B2%7D-4n%2B2%7D)%5E%7Bn%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $g(n)>0$, $h(n)>0$ when $n \to \infty$ and 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}g(n)=a, \lim_{n \to \infty}h(n)=b,$$ then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}g(n)^{h(n)}=a^b.$$

So

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2-4n+2})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2})^{ {\frac{n^2-4n+2}{2n-1}  (\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2} n)}}=e^2$$.

Comment: Trying to understand how you reached e^2 in the end

Comment: @user3133165 is it clear now.

Comment: Yes it is ,still trying to grasp when i should use these kind tricks when solving limits

Comment: @user3133165 If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi(n)=\infty$, then follows from the well known limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$ that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{\varphi(n)})^{\varphi(n)}=e$. Now let $\varphi(n)=\frac{n^2-4n+2}{2n-1}$, and you will see that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

After taking logarithm, observe that

$$n\ln(\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2-4n+2})=$$

$$n\ln(\color{red}{1}+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2})=$$

$$n\frac{2n-1  }{  n^2-4n+2}\frac{ \ln(  \color{red}{1}+\frac{2n-1  }{n^2-4n+2  } )  }{  \frac{2n-1  }{  n^2-4n+2 } }.$$

Now, use the well-known limit

$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac{\ln(\color{red}{1}+X)}{X}=1$$.

the limit is $e^2$.

Comment: Is there a power of $n$ missing?

Comment: $2n-1$, and $n^2-4n+2$ are different so the well known limit does not apply here.

Comment: @DeepSea please look now it is clear